# Prove that the only numbers not expressible as a sum of consecutive positive integers takes the form $2^n$ for some $n \in \mathbb N$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to prove the above question. As I see it this is the statement that needs to be proved: a number $x$ has no odd factors $\iff$ $x$ cannot be formed by a sum of consecutive natural numbers.

First ($\Rightarrow$):

Assume $x$ has no odd factors (i.e., $x = 2^m$ for some $m$). Seeking a contradiction write 
$$x = k + (k+1) + \cdots + (k+n) = (n+1)k + {n(n+1) \over 2} = {(2k + n)(n+1) \over 2}$$

Now $2k+n$ and $n+1$ are of opposite parity, therefore one of them is odd. You cannot form an odd number without an odd factor, therefore contradiction.

Second ($\Leftarrow$):

Assume $x$ has at least one odd factor. We seek to prove that $x$ can be written as above...This is where I'm stuck

Comment: Your question reads "not divisible by" rather than "not expressible as" so you need only to write the odd factor as a sum of consecutive integers - two should do it.

Comment: Fixed thanks @MarkBennet. Could you elaborate on why writing this odd factor as a sum of consecutive integers helps me? As in the comment below I'm having trouble seeing where this gets me.

Comment: Since any odd number is expressible in the manner suggested in the question, and a particular odd number is a factor of $x$, you have that $x$ is "divisible by$ an odd factor. I have put some comments in an answer to explain indicate why you can't use "expressible as" instead.

Comment: @Mark Bennet: Although I don't see a proof yet I still think it's likely that the conjecture with "expressible as" still holds since your methods is not a counter-proof. E.g. to express 14 with your method we would write $x=7 \cdot 2$ and see that since $7>2$ it won't work. But yet $14=2+3+4+5$ is expressable in another way as such a sum...

Comment: @Tintarn I didn't do even decompositions it is true - I'll make a note

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to complete the analysis of this situation, if there is an odd factor, so that $x=(2m+1)a$ then you can write $$x=(a-m)+(a-m+1)+\dots + (a-1)+a+(a+1)+\dots (a+m)$$ which is the sum of $2m+1$ consecutive integers. This can only be done with natural numbers if $m\lt a$ and there will be one such expression for each odd factor. To see whether it is possible choose the smallest odd factor - if it can be done at all, it can be done for that. So that is decomposition into an odd number of terms.

It is also possible to split $x=2ma-m=m(2a-1)$ into an even number of terms as is clear if we write the sum as:

$$(a-m)+(a-m+1)+\dots +a+ \dots +(a+m-1)=2ma-m$$

Again we clearly need the odd factor, and again this only works as an expression in positive integers if $a\gt m$. So we choose the largest odd factor in this case.

Any odd factor greater than $1$ can be expressed as the sum of two consecutive natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

An odd factor greater than $1$ is of the form $2m+1=m+(m+1)$

Comment: Sorry, I'm not sure I understand why writing $x = (m+(m+1)) \cdot 2^\alpha$ (if $x$ has one odd factor) helps me...

Comment: $m+(m+1)$ is the sum of two consecutive integers. By the way, since $x$ can have more than one odd factor, we only know that $x=(m+(m+1))d$, that is, $d$ needn't be a power of two.

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution. Although it's basically the same construction as in Mark Bennet's solution, I hope I can present some motivation here.

Assume we want to express $x=(2m-1)a$ where $a>0,m>1$ are positive integers.

First, note that $1+2+\dotsc+(2m-1)=m(2m-1)$ is divisble by $(2m-1)$. Set $a-m=d$. Then we obtain that
$(d+1)+(d+2)+\dotsc+(d+2m-1)=(2m-1)d+m(2m-1)=a(2m-1)=x$.

Now if $d \ge 0$ this means that we have found a suitable expression.

Assume $d<0$. Then the sum above is basically made of two parts:
One with the negative numbers $d+1,d+2,\dotsc,-1$ and one with the positive numbers $1,2,\dotsc,d+2m-1$. Note that $d+2m-1=a+m-1>1$.

Now, if we just cancel out the numbers which occur both with positive and negative sign we get the desired expression.

Writing formally, we then have a sum going from $-d$ to $d+2m-1$ or equivalently from $m-a$ to $a+m-1$.

So, we have a construction for all cases.
First, write $x=(2m-1)a$ where $a>0, m>1$.
If $a \ge m$ choose $k=a-m+1$ and $n=2m-2$.
If $a<m$ choose $k=m-a$ and $n=2a-1$.

Answer (score 0):

An algorithmic approach to finding such a sequence in any particular instance: For any number $c$ other than a power of $2$, $c$ will have at least one odd prime factor. Choose the  smallest odd prime factor of $c$, $p_i$. Let $b=\frac{c}{p_i}$. There are $p_i$ consecutive integers from $b-\frac{p_i-1}{2}$ to $b+\frac{p_i-1}{2}$ that sum to $c$. The average value of those integers is just $b$, so the sum is $p_i\cdot b=c$. Note that if $c$ has more than one odd prime factor, there may be several sequences of consecutive integers that sum to $c$.

As mentioned in another answer, an odd number $(d)$ is also the sum of two consecutive integers $\frac{d-1}{2}+\frac{d+1}{2}$. Also you already show that $2^n$ cannot be the sum of consecutive integers. That covers all cases.